# How to add Calender control into Textbox without using ajaxtoolkit

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How to add *Calender Control* into `Textbox` without using `ajaxtoolkit` in `asp.net`.

Comment: You should elaborate your question.

Comment: Use jQuery datepicker then

Comment: @Alex I want to add Calendar control into Textbox..means when i will click on textbox to enter the value then a calendar popup..then after selecting a date calendar automatically hide and selected date should be textbox (using asp.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about using jquery to add the calendar?

Take a look: [Jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: this is good. Is any way to add this using only asp.net or html controls

Comment: You can use asp.net controls and / or standard html controls. Take a look at the link I added and "View Source" on the page. To use jquery, you need to download jquery and jquery UI then you can use any of the features that jquery and the UI component have to offer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using following jquery and code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtStartDate").datepicker();
        $("#txtEndDate").datepicker();
    });
 </script>
```

// in above code txtStartDate and txtEndDate is id of your text box

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ...

**CODE**:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
 <script>
   $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: How do I receive value datepicker in aspx code behind file?